# Help me decide if I'm ready or not for this research topic

Tags: advice, research

so a bit of background info on me.

I'm a math grad student. My undergrad classes were mainly math-theory based stuff. I took Number Theory, Intro to Analysis, Intro to Abstract algebra, and such.

I did take some computationally sweaty courses such as Financial Math for Actuaries(sweaty, but fun!). I also took Intro to Probability. And of course, I have the basics such as differential equations, linear algebra, complex variables...

My professor told me he could assign me stuff related to **optimization**(for example a minimal-time control problem). He said if I knew my stuff, he could assign me something on single-cell RNA sequencing data analysis, which is basically a study on **large scale sparse matrix**. He also proposed a topic on **stochastic control** which would be challenging to both him and me.

**Can someone let me know what I'd be getting myself into** if I chose to do research with him? I honestly have no idea what I'd be getting myself into.

Appreciate any feedback. !~

Comment: I don't know if this is the right place to ask but I have read somewhere a user asked a similar question and I seem to agree with majority that do not rush to do research!!!. Give yourself some time to learn more and more. I as a third year undergraduate having taken real analysis, numerical linear algebra, and soon functional analysis I learned from my professors that unfortunately there are so many beautiful things about these fields that we don't learn at such level that they are plenty and abundant so give yourself some time to explore more about your field of interest first.

Comment: @T.H.Shehadi I don't have a choice!! I have to start research as a math grad student!! haha. And no matter who I choose, I'm going into something I don't have much of a foundation in. Also, I'm kind of like... done with proof based math. So this stuff may just be what I need to do...

Comment: @T.H.Shehadi You make a very valid point. But, I am under the assumption that OP is in their first years as a graduate math student and presumably passed their prelim exams. If so, then there is usually a deadline for the student to make a decision on who they're working with. In my case, I was given 6-8 weeks after passing prelims to decide. But again, you bring up a valid point.

Answer (score 0):

To be honest, it is hard to say whether or not you are ready for this research topic. It doesn’t really have anything to do with your background, your background should be fine for a topic like optimization. I am by no means an expert in optimization, but I can say that for applications, all you really need is a working knowledge of numerical linear algebra, vector calculus, and experience with programming (in Matlab for example). Some depth in topics like convex and set-valued analysis would be a plus, but are not essential.

That being said, being ready for a research topic is not necessarily dependent on your mathematical background alone. It also has a lot to do with your attitudes towards learning as a whole, and having a growth (as opposed to a fixed) mindset. In other words, things like:

- How well do you learn from your mistakes?
- How do you view failure/rejection?
- How well do you work with others?
- Are you open to learning new subjects/topics?
- Can you synthesize prior information and come up with new approaches to solving problems?

It is really subjective, so a definitive answer is hard to give. I should also note that in practice, you will learn what you need to do research on the go. I haven’t met (yet) an advisor who expects their mentees to know absolutely everything about their research the first semester.

These are my 2 cents, take with a grain of salt.

Comment: Yooo. Thanks. That's actually a really nice piece of advice there. It makes a lot of sense as well. I guess I should just go with my gut here and do it ~ I typically like being challenged so yeah, hitting walls is my kind of thing lol. Plus, I kind of don't have a heavy work load... I guess I kind of assumed it might just be a -learn it as u do it- kind of thing, but I really wanted to hear it from an experienced person. Thanks again. I'll probably just take on the challenge.

Comment: @Jonathanburrito Best of luck! Yes, remember that life is all about taking calculated risks. So give research a try, you will never know whether you'd succeed if you don't make the first step. A while back, I stepped outside of my pure math comfort zone and started studying applications to mechanical engineering. I had no experience back then with mechanical, but found myself very passionate about the subject and wanting to learn more.